# What might be the error in this java program?

Tags: java, string

```
public class One {
   static String s1="hello";
   static String s2="world";

   String display(s1,s2){ return s1+s2; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s3=display(s1,s2);
    System.out.println(s3);
   }
}
```

I am trying concatinate two strings by passing them yo user defined method, but its not working!!!
I know there is no need of any such method, but i request anyone helps me with this, i want to see how to pass two strings into method and then how to return the concatinated string using + operater

Comment: "its not working" is never enough information. What are you seeing, and what do you expect to see? Always include this information in a question. In this case it's easy to see what's wrong (you haven't specified types for your parameters, and your method isn't static) but we shouldn't have to spot that for ourselves - you should have included the compiler error message.

Comment: `display()` method is not *static*. Either make it static or call it using an instance of `One`.

Comment: Also, there are no definitions for the given parameters type. Which Java version you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the method display static.

```
public class One {
   static String s1="hello";
   static String s2="world";

   static String display(s1,s2){ return s1+s2; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s3=display(s1,s2);
    System.out.println(s3);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create an object of One and call display method

```
One one = new One();
String s3=one.display(s1,s2);
```

Hope that will help.

Also declare the arguments and initialize them

Answer (score 1):

Your `display` method is not `static`. Either make it `static` by changing

```
String display(s1,s2)
```

to

```
static String display(s1,s2)
```

or create an instance of the class using

```
One o=new One();
```

and call the method using

```
o.display(s1,s2);
```

You also have to specify the type before the argument. So change

```
String display(s1,s2)
```

to

```
String display(String s1,String s2)
```

Also,since `s1` and `s2` are global variables,they need not be passed as arguments to the `display` method.